# Building an ontology of national identity

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology, rdfs

I am working on a national identity ontology project, and I am trying to express the rules by which a person is granted national citizenship.

One of these rules states that a person has the right to acquire the original nationality if he is born of a national father, regardless of whether the mother is a national or a foreigner.

Also, a person can obtain national citizenship if he was born to a national mother, provided that the father is stateless or of unknown nationality.

Can you help me express these rules in OWL? I tried to do this, but it seems to me that there is an error.

```
    <SubClassOf>
        <Class IRI="#AbsoluteRightOfBlood"/>
        <Class IRI="#BirthFromNational"/>
    </SubClassOf>
    <SubClassOf>
        <Class IRI="#AbsoluteRightOfBlood"/>
        <ObjectAllValuesFrom>
            <ObjectProperty IRI="#bornFrom"/>
            <ObjectIntersectionOf>
                <Class IRI="#Father"/>
                <ObjectAllValuesFrom>
                    <ObjectProperty IRI="#hasNationality"/>
                    <Class IRI="#SelectedNationality "/>
                </ObjectAllValuesFrom>
            </ObjectIntersectionOf>
        </ObjectAllValuesFrom>
    </SubClassOf>

`

    <SubClassOf>
        <Class IRI="#AbsoluteRightOfBlood"/>
        <Class IRI="#BirthFromNational"/>
    </SubClassOf>
    <SubClassOf>
        <Class IRI="#AbsoluteRightOfBlood"/>
        <ObjectAllValuesFrom>
            <ObjectProperty IRI="#bornFrom"/>
            <ObjectIntersectionOf>
                <Class IRI="#Father"/>
                <ObjectAllValuesFrom>
                    <ObjectProperty IRI="#hasNationality"/>
                    <Class IRI="#SelectedNationality "/>
                </ObjectAllValuesFrom>
            </ObjectIntersectionOf>
        </ObjectAllValuesFrom>
    </SubClassOf>`


 <SubClassOf>
        <Class IRI="#RestrictedRightOfBlood"/>
        <Class IRI="#BirthFromNational"/>
    </SubClassOf>
    <SubClassOf>
        <Class IRI="#RestrictedRightOfBlood"/>
        <ObjectAllValuesFrom>
            <ObjectProperty IRI="#bornFrom"/>
            <ObjectIntersectionOf>
                <Class IRI="#Father"/>
                <ObjectAllValuesFrom>
                    <ObjectProperty IRI="#hasNationality"/>
                    <ObjectUnionOf>
                        <Class IRI="#StatelessNationality"/>
                        <Class IRI="#UnknownNationality"/>
                    </ObjectUnionOf>
                </ObjectAllValuesFrom>
            </ObjectIntersectionOf>
        </ObjectAllValuesFrom>
    </SubClassOf>
    <SubClassOf>
        <Class IRI="#RestrictedRightOfBlood"/>
        <ObjectAllValuesFrom>
            <ObjectProperty IRI="#bornFrom"/>
            <ObjectIntersectionOf>
                <Class IRI="#Mother"/>
                <ObjectAllValuesFrom>
                    <ObjectProperty IRI="#hasNationality"/>
                    <Class IRI="#Selected Nationality"/>
                </ObjectAllValuesFrom>
            </ObjectIntersectionOf>
        </ObjectAllValuesFrom>
    </SubClassOf>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're asking, But why are you using `allValuesFrom` here? Isn't the only restriction that the father has to have particular nationality? Not that I understand your goal at all, but once you have to refer your nationality to that of the father you'll most likely need an SWRL rule

Comment: Can you please add a minimal complete ontology along with the outcome you expected, as well as a description of the error you are getting?

Comment: Yes, the restriction is that the father has to have particular nationality, but it depends on the moment of birth of the person, if the father at the birth of the child had the specified nationality, then he will transmit it on to the child directly. Can you please help me express it using SWRL